# How Do I Switch From Dual Boot to VM?

Tags: 13.04, dual-boot, windows

My computer is currently dual booted with Ubuntu 13.04 and Windows 7. I'd like to just have Ubuntu installed, and run Windows in a virtual machine. What would be the best way to do this without losing any files?

Answer (score 1):

A good way to convert your physical Windows 7 install to a virtual machine would be to use VMWare's free converter tool: http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/

After you've done that, you can wipe Windows off your machine. This describes a way to do it: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToRemoveWindows

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be you take a backup of all the files to a external drive from the windows partition OR just copy the data to the Linux/Ubuntu partition.(just for safety).

From here on there are two options.

**Option ONE:**

One is create a image of the Win7 OS (you can easily find links on Google),

Create a boot-able disc or thumb-drive and load that bootable as a VM on your VM program (i prefer "virtual box" or VM ware, which ever suits your style).

Follow instructions accordingly for making images,And you might not lose the installed programs if you make a good image.

**Option TWO:**
Just Wipe your windows.

Extend the Ubuntu/Linux Partition to the free space.

Install fresh copy of windows on VM and install the required softwares.

***Things to consider:***

*1.This assuming you have already ample space to run your VM (say 20Gb would be a minimum)*

*2.Do you have enough ram ?(I have a 4gb ram on my laptop and VMachines are irritatingly slow)*

*3.Would you be using Windows for lot of I/O jobs (like digital cameras, networking,gaming because VMachines are under a certain limit in terms of peripherals)*

Answer (score 0):

As it may in theory be possible to convert a bare metal installation of Windows into a virtual machine I would not recommend doing so.

Keep in mind that other than Ubuntu a Windows installation will be very different depending on the hardware (e.g. loading different kernels, licence key depends on hardware, drivers are only loaded when the hardware is present). This hardware will be gone after moving to a VM, and Windows may then not run at all.

A much better and a stable way to have a lean and functional installation of Windows running as a guest on Ubuntu is to install it there from scratch. As you may not need much of the Windows add-ons because you do most of the tasks on the host you may want to shrink the Windows as much as possible.

Now these are the steps I would recommend you take:

- Make a backup of your data to be able to restore then in any case
- Shrink your Windows using tools like [nLite](http://www.nliteos.com/) (for XP) or [RT7lite](http://www.rt7lite.com/) (for Windows 7)
- Install the optimized Windows in a VM
- **Share** your data partition with the VM to also be able to access it from Ubuntu
- Exhaustively test your virtual Windows and make a backup before deleting the original installation